# how to inject Application scope bean on rest web service java

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have to inject initApplicationContext bean on ContextCacheRefresh web service, but unsuccessful, initApplicationContext value always is null. Have anybody any idea haw to deal with it?

```
@ManagedBean(name = "initApplicationContext", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
   public class InitApplicationContext {
             .......................
               }
```

and  web service

```
  @Path("/serviceContext")
  public class ContextCacheRefresh  {

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{initApplicationContext}")
    private  InitApplicationContext initApplicationContext;

  @GET
  @Path("/refreshContext")

 public Response refreshUserListOn(@QueryParam("param") String param
  ) { ......
```

Comment: Is this a JSF application? If it's not, you should be using `@Inject`

Comment: yes,it  is jsf application

Comment: Not really: you're trying to inject a JSF resource into a non-jsf context; not going to work.

Comment: Use `@Named` annotation instead of `@ManagedBean`, and `@Inject` to inject it to your restful service. Managed beans are just controllers for jsf pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not be able to get JSF to inject resources into a non-JSF context, using `@ManagedProperty`. Your options are

1. Convert your managed bean to use CDI annotations (`@Named` to declare the managed bean and `@Inject` instead of the JSF annotations you're working with now.
2. Just pull the bean from the plain servlet context using the following:

   ```
   //inject the servlet context
   @javax.ws.rs.core.Context 
   ServletContext servletContext

   public InitApplicationContext getInitContext(){
       return (InitApplicationContext)servletContext.getAttribute("initApplicationContext");
   }
   ```

---

What you're working toward seems a bit dodgy to me. Why is your web application concerned with your RESTful endpoint to begin with?

Comment: I'm working on separated multi modular web apps, all modules used the same instance of db . I have to reflect changes from one module to others, for that I choose to use web services.